# RSpec Devise Session Testing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, devise, rspec-rails

With rails 4.2.0 and the latest version of RSpec I generated a controller test.

How would I ensure my admin user is logged in?

For example: if current_user.admin?

In the rspec test it mentions it like so:

```
let(:valid_session) { {} }
```

How would I enter a valid session?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First you need to add the devise helpers in `spec_helper` file to be accessible in the tests, [as mentioned in the wiki](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Test-controllers-with-Rails-3-and-4-%28and-RSpec%29#controller-specs)

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include Devise::TestHelpers, :type => :controller
end
```

Then in the controller you could easily create a user object and sign it in using `sign_in` helper method

Comment: Or `include Devise::Test::ControllerHelpers` for Devise >= 4.1.1 as is now mentioned in the same wiki.

Comment: The mentioned wiki moved [here](https://github.com/heartcombo/devise/wiki/How-To:-Test-controllers-with-Rails-(and-RSpec)) for Devise >= 4.2.0.

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1:**
You can create custom methods like following in spec folder and then simply use them (after you have done what @Mohammad AbuShady's answer states which usually is done by default in rspec)

```
module ControllerMacros
  def login_admin
    before(:each) do
      @request.env["devise.mapping"] = Devise.mappings[:admin]
      sign_in FactoryBot.create(:user, admin:true)
    end
  end

  def login_user
    before(:each) do
      @request.env["devise.mapping"] = Devise.mappings[:user]
      sign_in FactoryBot.create(:user)
    end
  end
end
```

**Step 2:**

Add `login_user` or `login_admin` to your spec file wherever you need and change

`let(:valid_session) { {} }`

to

`let(:valid_session) { {"warden.user.user.key" => session["warden.user.user.key"]} }`

I hope you are using `devise` and `warden` which are really useful if you don't want to worry about session/login/signup issues.

You can see their documentations here:
[plataformatec/devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise)
[wardencommunity/warden](https://github.com/wardencommunity/warden)

This answer was written based on documentation of devise:
[devise-wiki-how-to-test](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Test-controllers-with-Rails-(and-RSpec))